# MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK is instant even though some buffered data remains

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, html5-audio

How to make Firefox seamlesly recover from temporary network errors during playback?

Consider this: we're playing a clip and we have some pre-buffered data ahead of our current position. At one point our browser decides to download next chunk of data. If it fails with e.g. "Connection refused", then Firefox stops playback instantly, fires "error" and sets "MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK" error code.

Chrome, however, keeps retrying with a growing delay between retries until it gives up and fires "error". If the network is restored until then, the user won't notice there was something wrong.

How I see this: even if I write some recovery javascript for Firefox, I won't be able to get rid of the noticeable pause during recovery. Right?

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio id="theplayer" controls src="2gb.wav" type="audio/wav" style="width: 100%;">
        </audio>
        <br/>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="theplayer.src = '2gb.wav';">reload</a>
    <body>
    <script>
        var theplayer = document.getElementById("theplayer");
        var currentTime;

        theplayer.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
            currentTime = theplayer.currentTime;
        }, false);
        theplayer.addEventListener("error", function () {
                console.log("error: " + theplayer.error.code + "; pos: " + currentTime);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if (!theplayer.playing) {
                        console.log("try recover");
                        theplayer.src = "2gb.wav";
                        theplayer.currentTime = currentTime;
                        theplayer.play();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }, false);  
        theplayer.addEventListener("abort", function () {
                console.log("abort");
            }, false);  
        theplayer.addEventListener("stalled", function () {
                console.log("stalled");
            }, false);  
        theplayer.addEventListener("suspend", function () {
                console.log("suspend");
            }, false);  
    </script>
</html>
```